# printf short in hex with uppercase in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to printf unsigned short in hex, e.g. 0XFFFF. The problem is that I want a lowercase x not X. I have no idea how to do this.

```
fprintf(c,"%#06X,\n\t", pixel[i]));
```

Comment: And the C++ tag just slipped in ...

Comment: `%X` is the wrong type specifier for `unsigned short` and `pixel[i] is the wrong type, too.

Comment: pixel[i] is unsigned short array.

Comment: I already presumed that. Still you pass an `int`. Just read about integer promotions and read the `printf` man-page resp. documentation resp. definition in the C standard.

Comment: I fixed it to this. fprintf(c, "0x%04X,\n\t", (unsigned short) pixel[1]);
not sure if it's right.

Comment: No, it is not. Why don't you read the documentation of functions you use? The information is available online. Oh, and about the `0x`: That is not possible automatically (I dislike this, too). But there is an obvious and simple solution. Remember you can have normal text in the format string, too.

Comment: @Olaf C11dr §6.5.2.2 6 "... the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: — one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;"   This allows `printf("%X", (unsigned short) pixel[1])` to work just the same as `printf("%hX", pixel[1])`.  Both are defined behavior as well as OP's `fprintf(c,"%#06X,\n\t", pixel[i]));`

Comment: @chux: Where did I state it was UB? It is not the correct types, though and can invoke implementation defined behaviour if `INT_MAX < `USHRT_MAX`. Why not use the type specifiers and types meant to be used for this?

Comment: @Olaf  If `INT_MAX < USHRT_MAX` then `(unsigned short) pixel[1]` gets promoted to `unsigned` and there is no  implementation defined behavior, just the usual defined behavior of printing an `unsigned` with `"%X"`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the %X specifier to %x and you should get lower case:

```
fprintf(c, "%#06x\n", pixel[i]);
```

Outputs the number as `0xffff`.  If pixel is an array of unsigned shorts and you want the format to match the data, you can do:

```
fprintf(c, "%#06hx\n", pixel[i]);
```

If you really want `0xFFFF`, then that's trivial:

```
fprintf(c, "0x%04hX\n", pixel[i]);
```

Comment: I suspect OP just wants the the `x` lowr case as he states in the question. Note that the argument has to be `unsigned int` to avoid implementation defined behaviour, which requires a cast.

Comment: There is no implementation defined behavior concerns here with or without a `(unsigned)` cast.   `"0x%04hX"` is certainly what OP is looking for.

Comment: @chux - I kind of feel your comment is the best answer given the short datatype and hex formatting.